# How can I get input connection from Jetpack Compose TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to capture `InputConnection` of `TextField` on focus change, the method was `onCreateInputConnection` in `EditText`. Is there such method? How to achieve it without using `AndroidView`?

Tried this but doesn't work either.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun KeyboardScreen() {
    val rootView = LocalView.current
    ...
    Button(onClick = {
        val inputConnection = BaseInputConnection(rootView, true)
        inputConnection.commitText("hello", 5)
    }) {
        Text(text = "test")
    }
```

Comment: I think you can achieve that with just compose `mutableStateOf` holder and `onValueChange` lambda. Could you elaborate on your use case?

Comment: I want to replace my IME connection from 'InputMethodService.getCurrentInputConnection()' to my own TextField inside IME

Comment: hey, have u solved this?

Comment: @galihif I have found a workaround that you can see in this PR: https://github.com/florisboard/florisboard/pull/1897

Answer (score 1):

That's nearly impossible at this point. I'm afraid you have to wrap the edit text. This is because `LocalTextInputService` is `staticCompositionLocalOf` and will cause all other composable to recompose and have the input service changed.

That would require you to write your own implementations of `PlatformTextInputService` and `TextInputService` class.

Then you need to provide the instance to the `LocalTextInputService` composition provider like:

```
class MyTextInputService : PlatformTextInputService {
   
}

class MyInputService : TextInputService(MyTextInputService()) {

}

@Composable
fun CustomInputServiceTextField(...){
    val inputService = remember { MyInputService() } 
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalTextInputService provides inputService) {
        TextField(value = ..., onValueChange = ...)
    }
}
```

This is just an idea.

Comment: How does this help in getting `InputConnection`?